# Does this stack exchange accept resource request questions?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to find a on a particular strand of book of French folklore, and I've had no had no luck with Google. I was wondering if the site policy allows me to ask for references here?

Comment: I am not aware of a policy against this.

Comment: We do have a source request tag you can use. But the tag description doesn't seem to follow what you want. Although the questions tagged to it don't either. (Looks like I'll have to tweak it.) What is the extant of what you want to know? Reading material, translations...?